# Why is an always followed by assign?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This might be a basic question to ask, but I have seen it many places and have not been able to figure out why this is the case.

```
always @(posedge clk)
  a_temp <= so;

assign a = a_temp;
```

What's the intent of using the extra assign statement here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a common misunderstanding on how verilog types work, that is if a modules port is connected to a wire, which it has to be, then the port should be defined as a wire inside the module. So you often get :

```
module example (
  output wire a_wire
);

  reg a_reg;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    a_reg <= so;
  end

  assign a_wire = a_reg;
endmodule
```

Which could just be:

```
module example (
  output reg a_reg
);

always @(posedge clk) begin
  a_reg <= so;
end
endmodule
```

At the next level of hierarchy `a_reg` is still connected to a wire.

### Interface Spec

Another technique that might be used with more experienced designers is to fix the interface. So that others wiring the block up have a fixed point of reference, and not having to deal with a designers constant name changes.  This allows the designer to use the most appropriate  (semantic) name for the signal making the code more readable while not being tied to the chosen interface name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The usual places where I have seen them inside if statement in the always block where the same LHS is driven more than once and finally once always block is executed, the result of the block is assigned to a wire.